# Type Error on line: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get the following error when running it: "Type Error on line 180: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".  Not sure if this is happening because there's an error in my code or if I'm not accounting for some edge case (i.e. array is empty). I also thought that the output is undefined in the second to last line because `const` is blocked scoped so the JS interpreter will not have access to the assigned value of output. But changing it to `let` did not make a difference and the same error still came up.

I'm trying to create a function that accepts an array and a callback, and returns an object. The function will iterate through the array and perform the callback on each element. Each return value from the callback will be saved as a key on the object. The value associated with each key will be an array consisting of all the elements that resulted in that return value when passed into the callback.

```
function groupBy(array, callback) {
//declare obj
  let obj = {}
  let value = [];
  //iterate through array and perform callback on each ele can accomplish this w/ for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let key = array[i];
    // value will be an array that you're going to push output into
      //return value = callback(array[i]) save this as a key to the obj
    let output = callback(key);
  }
  obj[value].push(output);
//return obj
  return obj;
}

//Test
const decimals = [1.3, 2.1, 2.4];
const floored = function(num) { return Math.floor(num); };
console.log(groupBy(decimals, floored)); // should log: { 1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4] }
```

Comment: Your `obj` is initialized as an empty object. No element inside it will have `push` method. I am referring to the line `obj[value].push(output);`.

Comment: The obj is initialized as empty because that's how it starts. What I'm trying to do is push the value generated from invoking the callback on the key (in this case each element of the array) into the object. Is there a better way to do that? –

Comment: You should initialize your object before push. eg- `obj[value] = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've create two variables.
One is an object (obj) and one is an array (value).
But you're trying to push data onto the object instead of the array (push isn't valid for objects).

Instead of:
`obj[value].push(output);`
You want something like:
`obj[key] = output;`

I don't think your callback is going to give you what you want though. I think there's some more work to do but hopefully the above unsticks your stuck.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve the problem. The key takeaway here drop push and use obj[key] = output inside the loop to assign each element as a key to the output value. It turns out that the callback worked as intended too.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome. I guess I must have misunderstood what the callback was doing. Glad you got it sorted!